# Queues not recreated after broker failure

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I'm using Spring-AMQP-rabbit in one of applications which acts as a message-consumer. The queues are created and subscribed to the exchange at startup.

My problem:
When the RabbitMq server is restarted or removed and added completely, the Queue's are not recreated. The connection to the RabbitMq server is re-stored, but not the Queues.

I've tried to do the queue admin within a ConnectionListener but that hangs on startup. I guess the admin is connection aware and should do queue management upon connection restore isn't?

My Queues are created by a service:

```
@Lazy
@Service
public class AMQPEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriber {
    private final ConnectionFactory mConnectionFactory;
    private final AmqpAdmin mAmqpAdmin;

     @Autowired
    public AMQPEventSubscriber(final AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin,
            final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            final ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        mConnectionFactory = connectionFactory;
        mAmqpAdmin = amqpAdmin;
        mObjectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public <T extends DomainEvent<?>> void subscribe(final Class<T> topic, final EventHandler<T> handler) {

        final EventName topicName =  topic.getAnnotation(EventName.class);

        if (topicName != null) {

            final MessageListenerAdapter adapter = new MessageListenerAdapter(handler, "handleEvent");
            final Jackson2JsonMessageConverter converter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
            converter.setJsonObjectMapper(mObjectMapper);
            adapter.setMessageConverter(converter);


            final Queue queue = new Queue(handler.getId(), true, false, false, QUEUE_ARGS);

            mAmqpAdmin.declareQueue(queue);
            final Binding binding = BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(Constants.DOMAIN_EVENT_TOPIC).with(topicName.value());
            mAmqpAdmin.declareBinding(binding);

            final SimpleMessageListenerContainer listener = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(mConnectionFactory);

            listener.setQueues(queue);
            listener.setMessageListener(adapter);
            listener.start();

        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("subscribed Event type has no exchange key!");
        }

    }
}
```

Part of my handler app:

```
@Component
public class FooEventHandler implements EventHandler<FooEvent> {
    private final UserCallbackMessenger mUserCallbackMessenger;
    private final HorseTeamPager mHorseTeamPager;

    @Autowired
    public FooEventHandler(final EventSubscriber subscriber) {
        subscriber.subscribe(FooEvent.class, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(final FooEvent event) {
      // do stuff
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why out-of-the-box feature with the `RabbitAdmin` and beans for Broker entities doesn't fit your requirements:

> A further benefit of doing the auto declarations in a listener is that if the connection is dropped for any reason (e.g. broker death, network glitch, etc.) they will be applied again the next time they are needed.

See more info in the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.6.0.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#automatic-declaration).

Comment: I know, very odd, I was expecting this from a managed context. Maybe good to say, I've removed the server completely and re-added it (using Docker). Somehow the Queues did not get recreated after the engine reconnected.

Comment: Could it be that it fails since I declare the Queues in the constructors of the handlers within my engine app?

Comment: Could. As I said: you have to declare queues, exchanges and bindings between them as beans: http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.6.0.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#broker-configuration

Comment: That sucks pretty much, since my application registers around 75 queues dynamically (see edit how)

Comment: Well, you can use `beanFactory.registerSingleton()` from your code there on the matter. But `RabbitAdmin` as a bean must be there anyway.

Comment: You can register your code with the connection factory as a `ConnectionListener` and re-declare the queues etc whenever the connection is established. That's how the `RabbitAdmin` does it.